# Invertir cadena en C++ usando iostream?

Tags: c++

estoy empezando en C++, me piden un ejercicio simple de palíndromos y no encuentro la forma de invertir una cadena de datos ya sea un string o un número sin utilizar nada mas que "iostream".
Alguien sabe algo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ¿Cómo se invierte una cadena?

Hay varias implementaciones que se pueden utilizar para invertir una cadena, según los requisitos del programa que está escribiendo. Veámoslos todos en orden.

### 1. Uso de la función inversa incorporada

C ++ tiene una reversefunción incorporada , que se puede llamar para invertir una cadena. Esta función toma dos entradas:

El iterador para el inicio de la cadena
El iterador para cadenas termina

El siguiente fragmento de código muestra cómo utilizar esta función:

```
#include <iostream>
//The library below must be included for the reverse function to work
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  string greeting = "Hello";
  //Note that it takes the iterators to the start and end of the string as arguments
  reverse(greeting.begin(),greeting.end());
  cout<<greeting<<endl;
}
```

### 2. Usando un loop

Dentro del maincuerpo de la función, se puede escribir un bucle para invertir una cadena.

En el cuerpo del bucle, utilizará la swapfunción, que está incorporada, para cambiar las posiciones de los elementos. En caso de que no se le permita utilizar ninguna función incorporada, la segunda pestaña de código muestra cómo realizar el ciclo inverso.

La tercera pestaña muestra cómo hacer la misma inversión con un ciclo while usando el método swap.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 
  string greeting = "Hello";
  int len = greeting.length();
  int n=len-1;
  for(int i=0;i<(len/2);i++){
    //Using the swap method to switch values at each index
    swap(greeting[i],greeting[n]);
    n = n-1;

  }
  cout<<greeting<<endl;
}
```

**Nota:** El bucle for solo se extiende por la mitad de la longitud de la cuerda, ya que se realizan intercambios entre la primera y la última posición y se mueven lentamente hacia adentro hasta que ambos iy nson iguales. El ciclo while muestra esta condición de forma más explícita.

### 3. Usando una función

También se puede escribir una función para invertir una cadena mediante la recursividad.

El siguiente fragmento de código muestra cómo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void reverse_String(string& greet, int n,int i){

  if(n<=i){return;}

  swap(greet[i],greet[n]);
  reverse_String(greet,n-1,i+1);

}

int main() {
  
  string greeting = "Hello";
  cout<<"String before reversal: "<<greeting<<endl;
  reverse_String(greeting,greeting.length()-1,0);
  cout<<"String after reversal: "<<greeting<<endl;
  
}
```

### 4.Creando una nueva cadena

Un método indirecto para invertir una cadena es hacer un bucle hacia atrás a través de ella y almacenar los elementos en una nueva cadena del mismo tamaño.

Para agregar elementos a una cadena vacía, podemos usar el método push_back.

El siguiente código muestra cómo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
  string greeting = "Hello";

  string new_greeting;

  for(int n = greeting.length()-1; n >= 0; n--){
    new_greeting.push_back(greeting[n]);
  }
  cout<<"Original string: "<< greeting << endl;
  cout<<"New reversed string: "<< new_greeting << endl;
  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Dado un string cualquiera:

```
std::string cadena = "abcdef";
```

Se puede invertir usando `std::reverse`:

```
std::string inversa = cadena;
std::reverse(inversa.begin(), inversa.end());
```

Se puede invertir usando el constructor de `std::string`:

```
std::string inversa(cadena.rbegin(), cadena.rend());
```

Puedes usar un bucle:

```
std::string inversa(cadena.length() + 1, '\0');
size_t index = cadena.length() - 1;
foreach (char c : cadena)
{
    inversa[index--] = c;
}
```

> no encuentro la forma de invertir una cadena de datos ya sea un string o un número sin utilizar nada mas que "iostream"

Es que `iostream` te ofrece únicamente un buffer de entrada que te va a devolver los datos en el mismo orden secuencial en el que han sido introducidos por el usuario.

La función de `iostream` es proporcionar mecanismos para interactuar con la entrada/salida. No está pensada para manipular dichos datos. La manipulación debe realizarse externamente

Answer (score 2):

Lee la cadena al revés<sup>1</sup> desde el flujo de entrada:

```
std::string lee_stream_al_reves(std::istream &i, std::istream::char_type final)
{
    std::string result;
    std::istream::char_type caracter = i.get();
    if (caracter != final)
    {
        result = lee_stream_al_reves(i, final) + caracter;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Este código:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << lee_stream_al_reves(std::cin, '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

[Genera la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##dZBBbsJADEXXmVO4QoKg0qrrNHACjlApsgaTWhpMNPFUKoizB9OhgQUs/fz99GXfdW8@oLTDMGHxIW0Iat73Ggl3K3djRljalXO9bqoqTxCImhxtMDSRfqgv//acKUx5Afegqvw3xkZ/O4ItC4a5O7riXhmpT0E/r/DBmceIXinCEvi9JS3nFuYtlOMCXpb/8sLsRVZa/lFdK5iz8DqqTXhyzu40RRkbGWJR2CFLeavt90mhrp@/wrMsYPYls0vPq/LDbMMQ0gHwkNbuDA) al introducir `"luz azuL"`:

```
Luza zul
```

---

<sup>1</sup>En realidad la lee en el orden normal pero después junta lo leído en orden inverso.